# How Url manager is working for Api's in Yii framework?

Tags: php, url, yii

Hi I have the following api url

```
http://localhost/apiworks/index.php/api/posts
```

how this url is managed(which controller, action) in the following code?

actually how this is working?

```
'urlManager'=>array(
    'urlFormat'=>'path',
    'rules'=>array(                 
           // REST patterns
              array('api/list', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
              array('api/view', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>/<id:\d+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),                       
              '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
        ),
```

Comment: It's the 3rd route, the native one that is being triggered. The other 2 don't match. Controller = ApiController, action is actionPost

Comment: @Blizz if i remove the first two , its not working. and also action name is posts right? while debugging but it goes to actionList in Apicontroller as expected

Comment: Btw, is that for Yii 2.x or something? Afaik Yii 1 does not support that structure for routes. Logic dictates it must be the first one then. The "posts" is threated as the model parameter and the action would be actionList('posts')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
array('api/list', 'pattern'=>'api/<model:\w+>', 'verb'=>'GET'),
```

It looks for actionList() function in ApiController for the case 'posts'